# How to have file connected to user account with Firebase

Tags: java, android, file, synchronization, storage

I'm in the process of developing an app for android and I'm using Firebase as my backend. I need a JSON file for each user and would like it to be connected to a user's account. How can I sync a file to someone's account through Firebase without the need for a database?